# Prove that $16(a\sin a + \cos a - 1)^2 \le 2a^4 + a^3 \sin 2a, \ \forall a\ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

> **Problem 1**: Prove that
> $$16(a\sin a + \cos a - 1)^2 \le 2a^4 + a^3 \sin 2a, \ \forall a\ge 0.\tag{1}$$

This is the stronger version of the following [Prove that $12(a\sin a+\cos a-1)^2\le 2a^4+a^3\sin(2a)$,$\forall a\in (0,\infty)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3332814/prove-that-12a-sin-a-cos-a-12-le-2a4a3-sin2a-forall-a-in-0-infty):

> **Problem 2**: Prove that
> $$12(a\sin a + \cos a - 1)^2 \le 2a^4 + a^3 \sin 2a, \ \forall a\ge 0. \tag{2}$$

For Problem 2, there is a very nice solution using Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality for integral [Prove that $12(a\sin a+\cos a-1)^2\le 2a^4+a^3\sin(2a)$,$\forall a\in (0,\infty)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3332814/prove-that-12a-sin-a-cos-a-12-le-2a4a3-sin2a-forall-a-in-0-infty).
Indeed, the inequality (2) is nothing but
$$12\left(\int_0^a x\cos x \mathrm{d} x \right)^2 \le 12\left(\int_0^a x^2 \mathrm{d} x\right)
\left(\int_0^a \cos^2 x \mathrm{d}x\right).$$

For Problem 2, I gave a complicated proof. See [Prove that $12(a\sin a+\cos a-1)^2\le 2a^4+a^3\sin(2a)$,$\forall a\in (0,\infty)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3332814/prove-that-12a-sin-a-cos-a-12-le-2a4a3-sin2a-forall-a-in-0-infty)

Are there any nice solutions for Problem 1?

Any comments and solutions are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: How did you obtain the value 16?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN Thanks for comment. The first positive zero of $a\sin a + \cos a - 1$ is $a_1 \approx 1.33$. Graphically, $\frac{2a^4+a^3\sin(2a)}{(a\sin(a)+\cos(a)-1)^2}$ is strictly increasing on $(0, a_1)$. Also, $\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{2a^4+a^3\sin(2a)}{(a\sin(a)+\cos(a)-1)^2} =  16$.
Second, graphically, $f(a) = 2a^4 + a^3 \sin 2a - 16(a\sin a + \cos a - 1)^2$ is strictly increasing on $a > 0$.  $f'(a) = 2a((2\cos^2 a + 3)a^2 - 13a\sin a \cos a - 16\cos^2 a + 16\cos a)$. We need to prove $(2\cos^2 a + 3)a^2 - 13a\sin a \cos a - 16\cos^2 a + 16\cos a \ge 0$. We may use my approach in the link.

Comment: In the nice solution to problem 2, the application of Cauchy-Schwarz is far from tight, since $x$ and $\cos x$ are not proportional. Maybe you can use a Cauchy-Schwarz defect inequality.

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks for valuable comment.

Comment: The command of Mathematica 12.2 `Minimize[{2 a^4 + a^3*Sin[2 a] - 16*(a*Sin[a] + Cos[a] - 1)^2, 
  a >= 0}, a]` produces `{0, {a -> 0}}`.

Comment: @user64494 Thank you for verifying it.

Answer (score 4):

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Preliminary notes.}}$

Dividing of the given inequality $(1)$ to $\;4a^4\;$ allows to present it in the equivalent form of
$$\left(2\text{ sinc } a - \text{ sinc}^2\,\dfrac a2\right)^2
\le \dfrac{1+\text{sinc }2a}2,\tag1$$
or $\;f_1(a)\le f_2(a),\;$ where
$$f_1(x) = \left(2\text{ sinc } x - \text{ sinc}^2\,\dfrac x2\right)^2,\quad
f_2(x)\le \dfrac{1+\text{sinc }2x}2.\tag2$$

[image: Inequality decomposition]

It suffices to prove the inequalities
$$f_1(x) \le (1-\,^1\!/_6\,x^2)^2\le f_2(x),\quad \text{if}\quad x\in\left[0,\dfrac\pi2\right],\tag3$$
and
$$f_1(x)\le \dfrac{4\pi-3}{8\pi}\le f_2(x),\quad \text{if}\quad x\in\left(\dfrac\pi2,\infty\right).\tag4$$

We can obtain the derivative
$$f_1'(x)= -\dfrac{8}{x^5}\,\sin x\left(\tan \dfrac x2-x\right)\bigg((x^2-2) \cos x - 2 x \sin x+2\bigg)\tag5$$
[image: f1(x) and f1'(x)]

The root of the derivative ar $\;x=r\approx\dfrac73\;$ corresponds to the root of $\;f_1.$

The root of the derivative near $\;x=m\approx 4\;$ corresponds to the secondary maximum of $\;f_1.$

$\color{brown}{\mathbf{\text{Interval }\left[0,\dfrac\pi2\right].}}$

Taking in account inequality $\;x^2<3,\;$ one can get
$$2\text{ sinc } x-\text{ sinc }^2\,\dfrac x2
 = 2\left(1-\dfrac16x^2+\dfrac1{5!}x^4-\dfrac1{7!}x^6+\dots\right)
 - \left(1-\dfrac16\left(\dfrac x2\right)^2+\dfrac1{5!}\left(\dfrac x2\right)^4+\dots\right)^2
$$$$
\le 2-\dfrac13x^2+\dfrac{x^4}{60} - \left(1-\dfrac{x^2}{24}\right)^2
\le 1-\dfrac14x^2+\dfrac1{36}x^4 \le 1-\dfrac14x^2+\dfrac1{12}x^2= 1-\dfrac{x^2}6,
$$

$$f_1(x)\le(1-\,^1\!/_6 x^2)^2.$$

Om the other hand,
$$\dfrac12\big(1+\text{ sinc } 2x\big)- (1-\,^1\!/_6 x^2)^2
 = 1-\dfrac1{12}\,(2x)^2+\dfrac1{2\cdot5!}(2x)^4-\dfrac1{2\cdot7!}(2x)^6+\dots -1 + \dfrac13x^2 - \dfrac1{36}x^4
$$$$
\ge\left(\dfrac1{15}-\dfrac1{36}\right)x^4\ge 0,
$$$$
f_2(x)\ge (1+\,^1\!/_6x^2)^2.
$$
Therefore, inequality $(3)$ **is proved.**

$\color{brown}{\mathbf{\text{Interval }\left(\dfrac\pi2,\infty\right).}}$

Since
$$f_1\left(\dfrac\pi2\right)=\left(\dfrac4\pi-\dfrac8{\pi^2}\right)^2
<\dfrac14<\dfrac{4\pi-3}{8\pi},$$
then
$$f_1(x)\le \dfrac{4\pi-3}{8\pi},\quad \text{if}\quad x\in\left(\dfrac\pi2,r\right].$$

At the same time,
$$f'_1(4.0)>0,\;f'_1(4.1)<0\quad\Rightarrow\quad m\in(4.0,4.1).$$
Then
$$f_1(m) - \dfrac{4\pi-3}{8\pi} < (\text{ sinc}^2 2 - 2\text{ sinc }4.1)^2 - \dfrac{4\pi-3}{8\pi} < 0,$$
and
$$f_1(x)\le \dfrac{4\pi-3}{8\pi},\quad \text{if}\quad x\in\left(\dfrac\pi2,\infty\right].\tag6$$

The least value of $\;\text{ sinc } x\;$ is situated near $\;x=\dfrac{3\pi}2,\;$ wherein
$$\text{ sinc }\dfrac{3\pi}2 = -\dfrac2{3\pi},\quad \text{ sinc }\dfrac{4\pi}3 = -\dfrac{3\sqrt3}{8\pi}>\text{ sinc }\dfrac{3\pi}2,\quad \text{ sinc }\dfrac{5\pi}3 = -\dfrac{3\sqrt3}{10\pi}>\text{ sinc }\dfrac{3\pi}2.$$
Taking in account unimodality of $\;\text{ sinc }x\;$ in$\;\left[\dfrac{4\pi}3,\dfrac{5\pi}3\right],\;$ the least value of $\;\text{ sinc }x\;$
belongs to this interval.
Therefore,
$$\text{ sinc }x>-\dfrac{\sin\dfrac{3\pi}2}{\dfrac{4\pi}3}=-\dfrac3{4\pi},$$
$$f_2(x)>\dfrac{4\pi-3}{8\pi }.\tag7$$
Therefore, inequality $(4)$ **is proved.**

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Done!}}$

Comment: @hd_30102 I am glad too